# Passing data from Component to another Component two files

Tags: angular

Hello I have a question about passing data between two components with two files.
I was wondering how I can pass data via @Input. Has someone an idea which way I have to pass the data?

```
file1.ts
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "search",
    templateUrl: '<div>Hello{{testData}}</div>'
})

export class File1Component{
public testData = "Hello";

}

file2.ts
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "profile",
    templateUrl: '<div>Hello</div>'
})

export class File2Component{


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create shared `service` or handle it like that:

file1.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "search",
    templateUrl: '
                  <div>Hello{{testData}}</div>'
})

export class File1Component{
public testData = "Hello";

getTestData(){
   return this.testData;
}

}
```

file2.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "profile",
    templateUrl: '<div>Hello</div>'
})

export class File2Component{
  @Input() inputData: any;

}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl:'<search #varSearch></search>
                 <profile [inputData]="varSearch.getTestData()"></profile>'
})

export class File2Component{


}
```

Comment: How can I pass the data in file1 into file2 with a service without creating an http request?If I add the <profile> tag then I am taking the template as well. I need just to pass the data.

Comment: No I didn't I am getting the the within the getData() Method but I am not able to print it outside from the method. I opened a new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822057/angular2-passing-data-over-servicestwo-components/39822467#39822467

Answer (score 0):

You can use `services` for that purpose. A service is an injectable singleton that can be passed to the components in their constructors. Both components communicate via the service, then.

You'll find a good and elaborate introduction to `services` in the official Angular2 documentation

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

There is also a live demo as a plunkr.