# Angular2 passing data over services(two Components)

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass data between two components via services. I am not sure how can I consume data via services from another component. I am getting the data from the 2. Component via getData() methode and saving it into the data variable. I can print it within the method but not outside from the method and also I tried to pass it to the first component. What is wrong with my code?

**1. Component file**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {PassProfileDataService} from '../common/PassProfileDataService';

@Component({

    selector: "profile",
    templateUrl: `client/components/profile/profile.component.html`

})

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit{
public data;

constructor(private _sharedService: PassProfileDataService){}

ngOnInit() {

this.data = this._sharedService.dataStringSource)
  }

}
```

**2. Component file**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {PassProfileDataService} from '../common/PassProfileDataService';

@Component({

    selector: "search",
    templateUrl: `client/components/search/search.component.html`

})
export class ProfileComponent{

constructor(private _sharedService: PassProfileDataService){}

this._sharedService.getData(data[0].values)
ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

**3. SharedService**

```
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class PassProfileDataService {

  public dataStringSource;

  // Service message commands
  getData(data: String) {
    this.dataStringSource  data;

  };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when your analysis lead you to identify a service as shared, you should register the Service in the app initialisation: this will let you access the same service instance in you Angular2 application. Practically, in your app.ts file...:

```
// other import statements...
import { TheNameService } from "./services/the-name.service";
// other import statements...

@Component({
    // other declarations...
    directives: [TheNameService]
    // other declarations...
})
```

Now import TheNameService with the import statement in each component that needs the service's instance. Remember to NOT insert TheNameService in the component's providers array or you'll get a NEW instance of the service in that component!!

This solves a piece of your question. In case the data to share is located into a public property of the service, you're set. But what if you're working with a complex service that's working with async methods? EventEmitters come in help.

In TheNameService declare a property of type EventEmitter where "type" is the type of data emitted by the event. I.e.

```
public myevent$: EventEmitter<string>;
```

In TheNameService's constructor remember to initialise the EventEmitter like this:

```
this.myEvent$ = new EventEmitter();
```

and every time the service have to share the data across the application:

```
this.myEvent$.emit("This is the emitted text!");
```

Remember to subscribe the component to the event... It's a good practice to store the subscription inside a component's property as we need to unsubscribe the listened events when the component is destroyed. First declare a new private property on your component:

```
private _myEventSubscription: any; // not sure about what kind of data type is returned here...
```

Subscribe to the service event in the ngOnInit method:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._myEventSubscription = this._theNameService.myEvent$.subscribe( (emittedString: string) => {
        console.log(emittedString); // will log "This is the emitted text!" in the console
    });
}
```

where the this._theNameService is the TheNameService injected with the dependency injection in the constructor (as following...)

```
constructor(private _theNameService: TheNameService) { }
```

Last thing to do, unregister the subscription in case of component destruction:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this._myEventSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: I tried but something is going wrong. Maybe you could explain it with my code above?

Answer (score -1):

Make a service that holds the data while you switch components. Below is an example.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TransfereService {

  constructor(
    private router:Router,
    private companyServiceService:CompanyServiceService
  ) { }

  private data;

  setData(data){
    this.data = data;
  }

  getData(){
    let temp = this.data;
    this.clearData();
    return temp;
  }

  clearData(){
    this.data = undefined;
  }

}
```

**Now Consider 2 components Sender and Reciever.**

*Senders code*: This code sets the data to the service and navigates to the receiver.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TransfereService } from './services/transfer.service';

export class SenderComponent implements OnInit {         
  constructor(
    private transfereService:TransfereService,
    private router:Router) {}

  somefunction(data){
   this.transfereService.setData(data);
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/reciever');//as per router
 }
}
```

*Reciever's Code*: This code fetches the data from service and clears the data as well.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TransfereService } from './services/transfer.service';

export class RecieverComponent implements OnInit {  
 data = this.transfereService.getData();       
 constructor(
   private transfereService:TransfereService,
   private router:Router) {
      if(this.data){
        // do whatever needed
      }
      else{
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/sender');
      }
   }
}
```